# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

Tags: java, url, ssl, java-6, diffie-hellman

I am getting below error while hitting HTTPS URL with Java code develoed in JDK1.6

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1649)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1612)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1595)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1172)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1149)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1019)
    at 
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
        at testHTTP.main(testHTTP.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:106)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:556)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:183)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1165)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DashoA13*..)
        at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:627)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:100)
        ... 13 more
```

What should be done in this case if I want to use JDK1.6 only..

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

When I have started using Java7, my issue was resolved but DH issue couldn't work with Java6